# Algolia vue-places: Clear input after selection

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, algolia

I'm using the [vue-places](https://github.com/Gomah/vue-places) component to render an Algolia places search input in Vue - it works brilliantly.

After a user selects / accepts a suggestion from the search dropdown, I want to clear the input and allow them to search again. Based on the standard example provided, I have tried to set `form.country.label` *v-model* value back to null in the change handler:

```
<template>
  <places
    v-model="form.country.label"
    placeholder="Where are we going ?"
    @change="selectLocation"
    :options="options">
  </places>
</template>

<script>
import Places from 'vue-places';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      options: {
        appId: <YOUR_PLACES_APP_ID>,
        apiKey: <YOUR_PLACES_API_KEY>,
        countries: ['US'],
      },
      form: {
        country: {
          label: null,
          data: {},
        },
      },
    };
  },
  components: {
    Places,
  },
    methods: {
      selectLocation: function(event: any) {
        if (event.name !== undefined) {
          /**
           * implementation not important
           */

          this.form.country.label = null;
        }
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

The `selectLocation` method fires as expected - but I cannot find any way to rest the input value to be empty.

How can I update a data value from a component method and have this reflected in a referencing component - in this case the Algolia places input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurs because of how `vue-places` is proxying `change` events from the underlying implementation. When a `change` event is received, it broadcasts the same event **and then updates the input value:**

[Places.vue](https://github.com/Gomah/vue-places/blob/bbd349c8952e2b4f7a878ded62444c7416d93127/src/Places.vue#L47-L50):

```
this.placesAutocomplete.on('change', (e) => {
  this.$emit('change', e.suggestion);
  this.updateValue(e.suggestion.value);
});
```

This means that any attempt to set a value in our change handler will immediately be overridden.

My solution is to create a `ref` to the `vue-places` instance and then use the built-in `Vue.nextTick` to use the internal `places.js` `setVal` method *after* the call to `updateValue`:

```
    methods: {
      selectLocation: function(event: any) {
        if (event.name !== undefined) {
          // do something with the value

          Vue.nextTick(() => {
            // clear the input value on the next update
            this.$refs.placesSearch.placesAutocomplete.setVal(null);
          });
        }
      }
    }
```